# Multiple networks in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I'd like to have 2 separate networks running in Theano at the same time, where the first network trains on the results of the second. I could embed both networks in the same structure but that would be a real mess in the entire forward pass (and probably won't even work because of the shared variables etc.)

The problem is that when I define a theano function I don't specify the model it's applied on, meaning if I'm having a predict and a train function they'll both work on the first model I define.

Is there a way to overcome that issue?

Comment: Why would it be a mess? You can always concatenate expressions, even a  posteriori, using e.g. `theano.clone(expression, replace={input_to_second_net: output_from_first_net}, strict=False)`

Comment: It would be a mess because I'll have to load a lot of things to the Theano model just to prepare the input and also I don't think it looks to clean to have 2 models combined into one. I'd much rather do it as said. By every input, I have to get some random results from the dataset, parse them using the stanford parser, convert the tree and then edit the results of the conversion, then run the first model on the results and only then I can send it to the final model, so it's quite a lot of preprocessing to do inside the model

Comment: I don't really understand what "as said" refers to. In what way random results from a dataset? Why don't you do the preprocessing outside the model? Nobody is forcing you to do inside the model if it is not convenient. You can easily pass data to a training function without passing by shared variables (although there might be an issue with GPU memory access that way)

Comment: That's exactly my point, I could either do preprocessing outside of the model and I could also integrate the 2 models together into a single one. I'd just like to avoid that and have my 2 models working separately because it makes more sense and is also more nicely organised.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a rather simplified way I've managed to find a nice solution. The trick was to create one model, define its function and then create the other model and define the second function. Works like a charm